# Creating model for existing AspNetUsers table in Entity Framework Code First Approach

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I am developing an Asp.Net mvc5 project. I am using Entity Framework code first approach to interact with the database. I am using Identity System for user authentication. But I am having a problem with integrating the AspNetUsers table from identity system to my model. My identity system database context and model database context class are different because I am using built in included identity system.

But connection string are same. Both use default connection string. But model is in different project. Now I am in the middle of the project. I have existing model classes mapped with tables in database. I created an user account from UI, so required tables(AspNetUsers table included) for identity system are auto-migrated. Now I want to create model class to map AspNetUsers table because I want to create relationship with between that AspNetUsers table and one of the existing tables. So I created a model class named "AspNetUser" class in my model project. Then I created properties for that class according to AspNetUsers table in database. Then I add migration and update database for my model. It gave me following error.

```
There is already an object named 'AspNetUsers' in the database.
```

What I can think is to delete AspNetUsers table and update database. But if I delete it, I have to delete other tables required for identity system because they have FK relationship. I do not want it. Second way I can think is to delete all required tables for identity system. Then migrate AspNetUser model class. Then delete that class and register new account from UI. So all required tables for identity system will be created again.

Second way also, I have to delete tables and happen data loss. How can I migrate overriding the existing AspNetUsers table? Is it possible? What is the best way to integrate AspNetUsers table to my model?

This is Configuration class in Migration folder

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<PatheinFashionStore.Domain.Concrete.StoreContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(PatheinFashionStore.Domain.Concrete.StoreContext context)
        {

        }
    }
```

This is my context initializer class

```
public class ContextInitializer : System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<StoreContext>
    {

        protected override void Seed(StoreContext context)
        {

        }
    }
```

If it is not possible, what would be the best way?

Comment: Just have your context inherit from IdentityDbContext. http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/01/03/asp-net-identity-with-the-entity-framework.aspx